# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I was create latest laravel project using

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test

After when i run php artisan serv then give me error like:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/test/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

After i was run composer dumpauto and solved my problem and after i run `php artisan serv` then still get error as:

> Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in
>   /var/www/html/sample-project/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Please help me and solve my issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you run command composer update in your terminal?

Comment: Yes i was run composer update command but no luck

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Just confirming something; when you ran `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel test`, did everything download properly, etc.? I ask because at this moment (for me, at least), api.github.com is having troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

Please run below command:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked removing "**vendor**" folder and "**composer.lock**" and then run:

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Watch step wise step in video tutorial for your problem**

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Expert Suggestion**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv1Jcq7AE64)

then after delete your vendor folder and then hit `compser install`